# Why does my program crash when run fine in the debugger but crash when run without the debugger in VS 2010 C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

So I am working on a graphics program for a college class. The teacher has a code but she the EXE. 
The code works. If I am in visual studio and go start the code with debugging it works fine. The program prints out instruction to the console via std::cout and then the opengl window appears and everything works as it is suppose to. 
However, if I go hit ctrl+f5 for run without debugging the instructions are printed out and the window appears but the content of the window is just pure white. After a minute or so the program crashes and a pop up from windows appears saying sorry the program crash or something along those lines.

If I go into the project folder and go into the debug folder and click on the .exe the instructions are printed out again and then a pop up saying “Debug assert fail” and it blames it on a vector index being out of range. This would make since except why does this not happen when I run the program in debug mode through visual studio?

If I am in visual studio and change the configuration from debug to release the instructions are printed again and this time a pop up saying bad memory alloc. It points to this line of code:

```
Model* mutiplyMatrix(Model model,CMatrix matrix)
{
    Model* m=new Model();
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<model.vectorList.size();i++)
    {
        CVector* v=new CVector();
        v->m=matrix*(*(model.vectorList.at(i)->m));
        v->drawBit=model.vectorList.at(i)->drawBit;
        m->addVectorToList(v);
    }
    return m;
}
```

The exact line is

```
CVector* v=new CVector();
```

So my question is how I can get an exe I could give to my teacher. I am fine with including the needed libraries and the like. The problem is that the program works but only when I execute it from visual studio in debug mode. The program crashes when used in either release mode or without debugging.

This is visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I sounds very much like you have an uninitialized variable that you're using and that influences the number of times that loop is executed.  In debug mode the value might consistently be set to a low value or 0 simply by nature of being run under the debugger.  However, when not running under the debugger, you're likely ending up with an extremely large value, which in turn causes the iteration above to run for an extended period of time and then crash when it runs out of memory.  I would track backwards from `model.vectorList.size()` to see where the value is coming from.  I would also add a `cout` line before you enter the for loop that prints out what the size is.

EDIT:

Well, I still think your problem is related to unbounded memory allocation related to an uninitialized variable, but there are a number of things you doing in your code that are hindering you

```
Model* mutiplyMatrix(Model mode,CMatrix matrix)
```

This is triggering a copy of both Model and CMatrix.  If your copy constructors or destructors aren't properly designed, that's going to be problematic, especially with your heavy use of raw pointer members.  Consider the following class:

```
class Foo {
  char * data;
  Foo() { 
    data = new char[1024];
  }
  virtual ~Foo() {
    delete[] data;
  }
};
```

Looks fine right?  I allocate the memory and I deallocate it.  But what happens if I have a function

```
void bar(Foo foo) {
  std::cout << "Called bar" << std::endl;
}
```

If I call that function with one of my foo objects, I'm corrupting memory.  `bar()` takes a Foo object, not a Foo reference, so my original Foo is simply copied before being handed to `bar()`. Because I didn't define a copy constructor, the default copy constructor is invoked, which means that the pointer value is just copied.  This means that when bar() ends, the pointer will be deallocated by the ~Foo() destructor on my class.  But then later when my original Foo instance leaves scope, the same pointer will be deleted again.  Memory corruption and crash.

At the very least your method should be declared

```
Model* mutiplyMatrix(Model & mode,CMatrix & matrix)
```

or preferably

```
Model* mutiplyMatrix(const Model & mode,const CMatrix & matrix)
```

Even worse, since we can infer from the source code below that Model has a member that looks something like this:

```
std:list<CVector*> vectorList;
```

When your incoming Model is copied and then destroyed, it's probably making big ol' mess of the heap.

My biggest piece of advice would be stop using so many damn pointers.

Comment: Sounds right, try placing a break point on the faulting line and look if all the field of all the objects are initialized. Also review the code for CVector's constructor as it might be faulty.

Comment: So I ran it through the debugger and the debugger can not find. Even when the memory is allocated the debugger says v is not a variable

Comment: 'v' isn't the important part.  the CVector constructor and the model.vectorList.size() values are your suspects.  Track down what is setting the vectorList.size() value and try sending that size to the output so you can see what it is before you app crashes.  If the debugger is failing you, you need to resort to console output and log files to tell you how far your apps is getting and what the internal state is at any point.  Start adding logging.

Comment: model.vectorList.size() is 603. It either runs once and then crash when it attempts to create a new CVector or it runs 6 times and on the 7 it crashes on addVectorToList, the contents of which is 'vectorList.push_back(c);'